# Как проверить существует ли сайт?

Tags: php

Возникла такая проблема: нужно проверить существует ли сайт, файл на сайте или страница.
Нашел такой код с curl, но он на рабочий сайт и не рабочий выдает всегда, что сайт рабочий:

```
    function is_url_exist($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($code == 200){
       $status = true;
    }else{
      $status = false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
   return $status;
}
```

Буду благодарен, если предложите решение

Comment: Приведите работающий и не-работающий адрес в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В PHP для этого есть штатная функция [**get_headers()**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php):

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

$code = get_headers($url)[0];

var_dump($code); // HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

Если сайт доступен, то код ответа будет 200, иначе будет другой код, значение которого можно найти в [**Википедии**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP).

---

Таким образом, вашу функцию можно существенно сократить:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

var_dump( urlExists($url) ); // true


function urlExists(string $url): bool
{
    return substr(get_headers($url)[0], 9, 3) == 200;
}
```

Comment: Это по сути есть то же что и у автора вопроса, отличается только метод получения кода HTTP, и не может считаться ответом.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov если то же, что у автора, то почему не может? - спасибо за отзыв. UPD: в отличии от метода из поста автора, предложенный вариант компактный.

Comment: Потому что автор не привел критериев адресов, по которым можно будет сделать такое различие. Сайты могут отдать и HTTP 200 с HTML с описанием ошибки что страница была не найдена.